# What metric does `Scalar test loss` in AutoKeras mean?

Tags: keras

I'm using the following code:

```py
import autokeras as ak

regressor = ak.StructuredDataRegressor(max_trials=100)
regressor.fit(x=train_dataset.drop(columns=['MPG']), y=train_dataset['MPG'])
# Evaluate the accuracy of the found model.
print('Accuracy: {accuracy}'.format(
    accuracy=regressor.evaluate(x=test_dataset.drop(columns=['MPG']), y=test_dataset['MPG'])))
```

The result of the `evaluate` function is [Scalar test loss](https://github.com/nocluebutalotofit/autokeras/blob/2efe5358f89c279ee4a7d615bb2bdca3e0ced3cb/autokeras/tasks/structured_data.py#L134). I just want to clarify what metric would that be. What is the default `loss` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `StructuredDataRegressor`, the default loss function is mean squared error. That information can be found in the `__init__` function with the default keyword argument [`loss='mean_squared_error'.](https://github.com/nocluebutalotofit/autokeras/blob/2efe5358f89c279ee4a7d615bb2bdca3e0ced3cb/autokeras/tasks/structured_data.py#L290)

Comment: I thought so too. But the output shows different values for loss and mse e.g.
`3/3 [==============================] - 0s 49ms/step - loss: 32.9195 - mean_squared_error: 25.9634`.

Comment: You might be confusing training and test loss. This first number is training loss, and the second number is test loss.